# Having trouble with calculation on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble creating a couple new calculated columns to my Dataframe. Here is what I'm looking for:

Original DF:

```
Col_IN    Col_OUT         
  5           2                     
  1           2            
  2           2         
  3           0          
  3           1
```

What I want to add is two columns. One is 'running end of day total' that takes in the net of the current day plus total of day before. Second column I want 'Available Units' - which factors in the previous day end total plus incoming units. Desired result:

Desired DF:

```
      Col_IN   Available_Units  Col_OUT   End_Total   
         5            5            2          3              
         1            4            2          2
         2            4            2          2
         3            5            0          5
         3            8            1          7
```

It's a weird one - anybody have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check rolling window (size of two): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 2):

For the `End_Total` you can use `np.cumsum` and for `Available Units` you can use `shift`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_IN': [5,1,2,3,3],
    'Col_OUT': [2,2,2,0,1]
})
df['End_Total'] = np.cumsum(df['Col_IN'] - df['Col_OUT'])
df['Available_Units'] = df['End_Total'].shift().fillna(0) + df['Col_IN']
print(df)
```

will output

```
   Col_IN  Col_OUT  End_Total  Available_Units
0       5        2          3              5.0
1       1        2          2              4.0
2       2        2          2              4.0
3       3        0          5              5.0
4       3        1          7              8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Running totals are also known as cumulative sums, for which pandas has the `cumsum()` function.

The end totals can be calculated through the cumulative sum of incoming minus the cumulative sum of outgoing:

```
df["End_Total"] = df["Col_IN"].cumsum() - df["Col_OUT"].cumsum()
```

The available units can be calculated in the same way, if you shift the outgoing column one down:

```
df["Available_Units"] = df["Col_IN"].cumsum() - df["Col_OUT"].shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum()
```